# Creating a SQL column based on the value of another column in the same table

Tags: sql

I must not be using the right Google foo to find the correct answer.

I have a table that looks like the following:

ID  Parent  Status   Name

1              NULL     0              Root

2              1              0              Group 1

3               6              400         WINXP32

4              2              400         WIN7

5              2              400         WIN2K8

6              1              0              Group 2

The 'name' column contains both group names and machine names. Groups have a 'Status' of 0.
How would I create a SQL statement to display (not modify the database) a column called 'Group' based on the logic that the 'Parent' column holds the 'ID' of its parent.

Somehow I can figure out how to join data from other tables but I cant figure this out...

-- Update: I forgot to show an example of the output I'm looking for, in a perfect world I would get the following..

ID   |   Group   |  Status    |  Name
3   |   Group 2   | 400   |  WINXP32
4  | Group 1  |  400  | WIN7
5  |  Group 1  | 400  | WIN2K8

I would (i think) filter out the groups from the output by doing a where status > 0

Thanks everyone for the quick feedback !

Comment: Could you show us the desired output for your sample table?

Comment: Plase show example output you are expecting and what database platform is this?

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Consider updating your question to show what the values of the 'group' should be. Also I suspect you want to use AS in a select statement.

Comment: Select name as group from tablename where status=0 and parent in (select id from tablename where status=0) , somethng like that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (Self join in SQL standard)?

If it's possible that you have records with missing Parent ID:

```
select t1.name,
       t2.name as "Group"
from tab t1
     left join tab t2
     on t1.parent = t2.id
where t1.status > 0;
```

If Parent ID is always present, you can use an inner join:

```
select t1.name,
       t2.name as "Group"
from tab t1, tab t2
where t1.parent = t2.id
  and t1.status > 0;
```

Otherwise, please can you explain what you need?

Comment: Corrado Piola for the win!!  Both statements did exactly what I needed. I decided to go with the first of the two to account for null parent ID records (there are a few).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try like thsi

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN (SELECT Root WHERE Parent  = ID)
       END [Group]
       Status,
       Name
FROM TABLE1
WHERE STATUS <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is to use the same table twice. This is achieved using different aliases like Corrado Piola explained it.

```
select t1.name, t2.name from mytab t1, mytab t2 where ...
```

Now t1 and t2 are acting like different tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Select 
     m.id,g.Name,m.Status,m.Name
     from
     table1 M,
     table2 G
     where
     m.Status >0  
     and g.Status = 0
     and m.Parent = g.id
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.